# How does $f\cdot m_\varepsilon - (f\cdot m)_\varepsilon$ converge?

Tags: measure-theory, distribution-theory, convolution, weak-convergence

Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous function with at most polynomial growth at infinity, and $m$ a finite (non-negative) measure, both defined on $X=\mathbb R^n$.
By $\bullet_\varepsilon$ we denote convolution with the standard mollifier $\varphi_\varepsilon$ on $X$, that is the density of the normal distribution  with mean $0$ and variance $\varepsilon>0$.

*Statement*: For any $\eta>0$ there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for all $z\in X$,
\begin{equation}
|(f \cdot m_\varepsilon - (f\cdot m)_\varepsilon)(z)|   \le \eta \cdot m_\varepsilon(z).
\end{equation}

How to prove it?

Comment: Let $m$ be a distribution which is a finite measure $f (m \ast \phi_\epsilon)$ is continuous so it is close to  $(f (m \ast \phi_\epsilon))\ast\phi_\epsilon$ and your question is how close is it to $(f m)\ast\phi_\epsilon$, one answer is to look at the $\sup$ of the derivative of the difference

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry, but I don't see the point. Do you mean that given $(f_n) \in C^\infty(X)^\mathbb N$ such that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ weakly and $\| \nabla f_n\|_\infty$ is uniformly bounded / converges to $0$, we necessarily have $f_n \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere? Could you explain this, please?